# resize and crop HD video into square video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to scale and crop HD video (1920x1080) into square one while adding watermark. I tried

ffmpeg 
-i video.mp4 
-i watermark.png 
-filter_complex "[0]scale=720:720,crop=720:720[a];[1]scale=720:720[b];[a][b]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" 
output.mp4

but it produces output with 889x500. Can anyone help me? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When executing your command, I get a 720x720 output, with 16:9 aspect ratio.

You may add `setsar=1:1` as used in the [Scaling example](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling):

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=720:720,setsar=1:1,crop=720:720[a];[1]scale=720:720,setsar=1:1[b];[a][b]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" output.mp4
```

Comment: Indeed, the metadata looks like 720x720 but when you check the output, the video is still in 16:9 instead of 1:1. I’ll try setsar. Thx.